# NSString to NSDate Wrong Result

Tags: ios, nsdate

In my iOS app I am trying to convert a date I get in string format into an NSDate. I first put the string in the correct format but when it comes to changing it into an NSDate I get a different output date. In the code below I have put two NSLogs which shows that the string matches the date format so I am lost as to why the output is different.

```
NSString * list = @"Sun, 24 Mar 2013 21:08:02 +0000";
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
//24 Mar 2013 21:08:02 +0000

NSArray *listItems1 = [[listItems objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *timeSubString = [[listItems1 objectAtIndex:3] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,5)];
NSString * newConcat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-%@ %@",[listItems1 objectAtIndex:0],[listItems1 objectAtIndex:1],[listItems1 objectAtIndex:2], timeSubString];
NSLog(@"***DATE STRING***: %@",newConcat);
//***DATE STRING***: 24-Mar-2013 21:08

NSDateFormatter* fmt = [NSDateFormatter new];
[fmt setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm"];
NSDate* date = [fmt dateFromString:newConcat];
NSLog(@"***OUTPUT DATE***: %@",date);
//***OUTPUT DATE***: 2013-01-06 02:08:00 +0000
NSLog(@"***DATE STRING***: %@", [fmt stringFromDate:date]);
//***DATE STRING***: 05-Jan-2013 21:08
```

Comment: If u read my code u would see: NSLog(@"***DATE STRING***: %@", [fmt stringFromDate:date]);

Comment: There are so many existing questions dealing with date formatting problems. Please look at those first.

Comment: I have and I keep seeing that people just don't format the date at the end. if u look I have formatted it and it still comes out wrong.

Comment: @Joe but the NSLog(@"***DATE STRING***: %@", [fmt stringFromDate:date]) which is formatted if u look at my log still comes out wrong

Comment: the date was: Sun, 24 Mar 2013 21:08:02 +0000. That is 3 months off

Comment: @BDGapps Please see the docs for the date format specifiers. See what you should be using for year.

Comment: YYYY vs yyyy thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same with this

```
NSString *dateString = @"Sun, 24 Mar 2013 21:08:02 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm"];

NSString *newDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```